# Lucene Basic Search Phrase Not weighted by complete sentance first

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, lucene

Been trying to get Lucene search to work for a simple example.
The user will be able to search with multiple words and I want to bring back some results where it has been weighted so that if the complete sentence is matched. This would have the highest score compared to results with only one word matched.

At the moment the search seems to split up the search term into individual words and never bothers to search for any complete sentences or part of a sentence.

I am unsure what I need to be passing into the Parser at moment. The below search returns a query with "Hello" and "Kitty" as separate searches.

```
    Query searchQuery = MultiFieldQueryParser.Parse(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, //  phrase,
                                    new string[] { "Hello Kitty"},
                                    new[]   { 
                                            "description", 
                                            },
                                    new[]   { 
                                            BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD, 
                                            BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD, 
                                            BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD, 
                                            },
                                    new Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer());
```

I'm sure this must be easy to implement but am unsure how to go about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do u mean by separate searches?

`description:hello OR description:kitty` ?

Even in this case, document with description that contains both hello and kitty will be most likely scored higher compared to the documents containing only hello or kitty (i'm assuming document length and repetitions of terms remain more or less same across documents)

You can also modify above query by appending a phrase query.

`description:"hello kitty" OR description:hello OR description:kitty`

Comment: but if we have a longer search term such as "Hello My Friend Kitty"

Then something with "Hello" appearing 3 times will rank higher or equal to something that has "Hello My Friend" within it (nearly exact match)

To do this test we would have to create a query which tests: 
Hello, 
My, 
Friend, 
Kitty, 
Hello My, 
My Friend, 
Friend Kitty, 
Hello My Friend, 
My Friend Kitty, 
Hello My Friend Hello, 

As you can see it gets very long very fast

Comment: true. that's the reason i have mentioned about my assumption. you can check DisjunctionMaxQuery (http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/da/d9b/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_disjunction_max_query.html)